# Way to force iOS action to wait until action before complete?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, action

I have an iOS action `- (void)download;` - which I have running at the launch of my iOS application.

However, I need another `- (void)showData;`- which displays data on a `UIMapView` to wait until all the data has been downloaded through `- (void)download` - before it begins. Just wondering if anyone knows a way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: How does the download method do it's download?

Comment: As aBitObvious asks...are you using NSURLConnection? NSOperationQueue? A little more information will help us gain a better understanding of your question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - but I'm using an NSURLConnection

Answer (score 0):

First send `- (void)download;` request and put a [progress hud](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) to the ui so user will know that you are downloading data, once you are done with download dismiss progress hud and run your `- (void)showData;` method

```
- (void)download{   
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        //display loading hud here 
    } else {
        // oh noes!
    }
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [receivedData setLength:0]; 
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {   
    [receivedData appendData:data]; 
    int kb = [receivedData length] / 1024;
    //dismiss hud here 
    [self showData];
}
```